# Friend and nonmember funcions dilemma

Tags: c++

I searched a lot about what I cannot understand but I really didn't find a proper answer to a little dilemma I have about "friend" and nonmember functions. So, here it is...

This is a sample code whose the pattern is similar to the respective codes I saw:

```
struct SampleClass
{
    friend void foo1(SampleClass &rhs);
    void foo2();
private:
    int bar;
};

void foo1(SampleClass& rhs)
{
    rhs.foo2();
}

void foo3(SampleClass& rhs)
{
    rhs.foo2();
}

int main()
{
    SampleClass samp;
    foo1(samp); //friend function
    foo3(samp); //not a friend function but has the same effect
    return 0;
}
```

Why how we use the nonmember class function which was identified by "friend" keyword is similar to the function which not? And why cannot the first function (the "friend"**ed** function) access "bar" variable by knowing that a "friend" function or class can access the private members of the host class?

Comment: I'm having trouble understand what you mean. `foo2` is clearly public. Try to type `rhs.bar=5;` instead of `rhs.foo2();` then you'll see the difference.

Comment: Please include code for what you're confused about. As it is there seems to be no question here. (`bar`, the only `private` thing, is never accessed.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function protocols need to match. Change:

```
friend void foo1();
```

To:

```
friend void foo1(SampleClass& rhs);
```

Comment: @atoi.powered What do you mean has the same affect, void foo2() is a public function...

Comment: Thanks Joseph. After re-reading and examining my codes for many times, I finally understood. The problem was that I didn't consider to test accessing the private member of the class in a nonmember class function and a normal function outside of the class. That was the thing I didn't know.